# How to create a new datatype in mpi and take effect in all scope?

Tags: c++, mpi

I define a new MPI data type in the main function in my code, but it seems that it can't be used in other functions.

```
typedef struct {
    int row;
    int col;
    double val;
} unit;

void sendTest() {
    unit val;
    val.row = val.col = val.val = 1;
    MPI_Send(&val, 1, valUnit, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

void recvTest() {
    unit val;
    MPI_Recv(&val, 1, valUnit, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int comm_sz,my_rank;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    int blockcount[3]={1,1,1};
    MPI_Aint offsets[3] = {offsetof(unit, row), offsetof(unit, col), offsetof(unit, val)};
    MPI_Datatype dataType[3] = {MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_DOUBLE};
    MPI_Datatype valUnit;
    MPI_Type_create_struct(3, blockcount, offsets, dataType, &valUnit);
    MPI_Type_commit(&valUnit);

    if(my_rank == 0)
        sendTest();
    else
        recvTest();

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the program, I got an error:

```
error: ‘valUnit’ was not declared in this scope
```

I was wondering how to define the new mpi data type once and can be used in all scope?

Comment: you could write a function that returns a `MPI_Datatype` which is your `valUnit`, then whenever you need it you call that function

Comment: note that `valUnit` isnt really a type but a value of type `MPI_Datatype` so you basically pass it around like you would do it with any other value

Comment: You can simply pass `valUnit` as a parameter to `send()` and `recv()`.

Comment: @user463035818 This method is available, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Evg This method can also make the program run normally, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply declare `valUnit` as a global variable (e.g. right after the `typedef ...` declaration).

Note `send()` and `recv()` are functions from the `glibc` so you should rename these subroutines in your program, otherwise you might experience some really weird side effects.

Comment: You‘re right, I re-edited the question. And your method is available.